# N balls and M ball probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, combinations

You are throwing n balls into m bins randomly.

What is the probability to be empty of the first s bin?

Given k bins are empty. What is the probability to be empty of (s+1)th bin?

I get the first bin empty probability, but I can't figure out the s'th.

Edit: Solved.

Comment: A [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542248/probability-of-throwing-balls-into-bins) was asked recently. While the answer only addresses the probability that the first bin is empty, you can use similar reasoning to deal, for example, with the probability that the first $2$ bins are empty, and then with the general problem.

Comment: I believe I solved the problem. What would be the probability that the first 2 bins are empty, however?

Comment: Perhaps you can tell me the answer you got. I will tell you whether you are right.